# How can I route drag events in C# UserControl?

Tags: c#, user-controls, drag-and-drop

My intention was to write a LabelOrText UserControl that behaves like a Label or like a TextField - depending on a mode parameter in its constructor.
The UserControl has a Text Property and it contains a Label and a TextField - but only one of both can be visible at a time.
So in any Application Source I can now replace all the Labels and all the TextFields with my LabelOrText UserControl without changing any source code ...
(Of course, not only the Text property is delegated to the visible inner control, also the Font property and the BackColor property and all the other properties are delegated to the visible inner control ...)

This works fine, except the DragOver and DragDrop Events don't work es expected.

--> LabelOrText1.DragDrop += myDDHandler should work like Label1.DragDrop += myDDHandler

--> LabelOrText1.DragOver += myDOHandler should work like Label1.DragOver += myDOHandler

and

--> any DragOver action on the inner Label with the mouse should call the myDOHandler(o, e)

--> any DragDrop action on the inner Label with the mouse should call the myDDHandler(o, e)

---

so it would be really simple to replace the Label Controls with my LabelOrText UserControl in any Application's Source Code.

---

Any Ideas on how to transparently route the Drag-Events from the inner Control through the UserControl will be highly appreciated!

Comment: A control that behaves like a label or a text box?  Why not just a read only or disabled text box?  Seems like a lot of trouble for nothing.

Comment: the disabled TextBox shows the Text always greyed and the
readonly TextBox shows a blinking Cursor within the Text - both is inadequate to emulate the Label's behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textbox alone sounds fine, but if you want to handle drag drop in a parent container, just set the DragDrop events of the label,text and self to the parent/self;

You can do this transparently by wiring up the events in the parent class, and it should be pretty easy.

in Parent object CTOR or elsewhere

```
//psuedocode
label.DragDrop += parentEvent;  //aggregate object
text.DragDrop += parentEvent;
DragDrop += parentEvent;
```

I did this with a panel, such that anything that was pushed and dragged cause the whole thing to follow your finger/mouse and scroll. Panning.

Comment: I see! In case the parent Events have already been added I will try something like this: innerLabel.DragDrop += this.DragDrop in my UserControl's reload() method.

Comment: oops, this did not help.
C# does not compile the line innerLabel.DragDrop += this.DragDrop;
please help me - how can I assign the parentEvent to the inner control?

Comment: partly solved:
partial source of LabelOrText Usercontrol:
  public event DragEventHandler DragOver;
  public event DragEventHandler DragDrop;
  private void control_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   lblString.DragOver += this.DragOver;
   lblString.DragDrop += this.DragDrop;
   txtString.DragOver += this.DragOver;
   txtString.DragDrop += this.DragDrop;
  }
It works. In the Form's Eventhandler you cant make decision like "if (sender == myLabelOrText1)" - you must write the decision like "if (((Control)sender).Parent == myLabelOrText1)"
- so the solution isnt really transparent

Comment: I'm doing a test case - hang on.

Comment: I wired everything in the UserControl like this: label1.DragOver +=     new DragEventHandler(this.LabelTB_DragOver);
            label1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.LabelTB_DragDrop);
            textBox1.DragOver +=new DragEventHandler(this.LabelTB_DragOver);
            textBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.LabelTB_DragDrop);

Comment: Make an event handler in UserControl that looks to see if the userControls DragDrop is hooked up, and if it is, trigger it.

Comment: CharlesW I am sorry. My solution worked but this solution does not fire any event, my Application does not react on anything.
The form that holds all the LabelTB controls does not receive any DragDrop event or DragOver Event. Clearly the LabelTB_DragDrop is never triggered because the inner label spreads above the whole UserControl. This Version of LabelTB can not replace all the Labels in my Application. There must be some misunderatnding. Should I put some code into the LabelTB_DragOver() Method?

Comment: If you have a small test project, with form and control, I'd be happy to help you with it.  Not sure how that works on stack overflow though, personal contact.

Comment: If you want to do that, look up my profile, register on my website with a username that I will catch, and then I'll mail ya back.  I think that's the easiest way to do it without giving out info here.

Comment: Dear CharlesW I thynk you for halp but I fear that I will not find time. My solution works. I will give you codelet if you contact me at mail dot com